# How to use the methods of a subclass of a superclass in another class in which I created a ArrayList<SuperclassName>?

Tags: java

How to use the methods of a subclass of a superclass in another class in which I created a ArrayList?

I created a ArrayList of a superclass in another class. This superclass has three subclasses, each with their own methods. How do I use those methods?

And also, how can I use the instance variables of those subclasses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you used the name of the superclass as your generic type, you are using the interface that the superclass provides in the ArrayList.

You can add subclass types to the list, but you cannot safely use unique methods introduced in the subclasses without first checking exactly which subclass the object is, then making a cast to the subclass.

Here is an example:

```
public class A {

    public void methodFromA() {
        System.out.println("From class A");
    }

}


public class B extends A {

    public void methodFromB() {
        System.out.println("From class B");
    }

}

public class C extends A {

    public void methodFromC() {
        System.out.println("From class C");
    }

}
```

and here are these classes in use, using an ArrayList with the superclass type:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<A> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    A object1 = new A();
    B object2 = new B();
    C object3 = new C();

    myList.add(object1);
    myList.add(object2);
    myList.add(object3);

    for (A object : myList) {
        object.methodFromA();

        if (object instanceof B) {
            B castedObject = (B) object;
            castedObject.methodFromB();
        }
        else if (object instanceof C) {
            C castedObject = (C) object;
            castedObject.methodFromC();
        }
    }
}
```

the resulting output:

```
From class A
From class A
From class B
From class A
From class C
```

As far as using instance variables, they should be accessed by public getters and setters, used after checking and casting, as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are not able to call super class method which will reflect to concrete subclass it means your design isn't good, you should thing it again.

But, anyway you can get item from arraylist and check it using `instanceof` like:

```
if (item instanceof FirstSubClass){
   FirstSubClass f = (FirstSubClass) item;
   f.methodInFirst();
} else if (...)
   .....
```

Comment: And how can I use the instance variables of that specific subclass?

Comment: If I created a ArrayList of superclass type how can I add objects of subclass type to that ArrayList if they have different constructors (with other parameters).

Comment: the constructor of an object must be called before you can add the object to the list. therefore, you can use whatever constructor you want at the time of the creation of the subclass object.

Comment: It doesn't matter, feel free to create any kind of objects using various constructors, main point is all your objects which u will add to list should be subclass of Superclass

Comment: so for example if I have ArrayList<Course> course = new ArrayList<Course>(). Course is the superclass and Major is a subclass of Course. If I want to add an object of type Major to ArrayList<Course> I have to do course.add(new Major(....)) ?

Comment: Exactly, why not?

Comment: @Vasif I don't know how to add different types of subclasses to a ArrayList through a method cointained in the class with the ArrayList. How can I do it?

Comment: I just can't understand what exactly u want to do. Could u please edit your question and add all classes and let me know what exactly u want to do. My answer covers your current question, but seems like u need something different or your question isnt clear